# Laravel Omnipay-Mollie error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, omnipay

Im trying to make a payment system on my website with [Onmipay-Mollie](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-mollie/) and [Barryvdh-Laravel-Omnipay](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-omnipay)

When i want to make a 'payment', and submit the form used to make a payment. I'm getting an error:

```
Omnipay \ Common \ Exception \ RuntimeException

This response does not support redirection.
```

My Routes file:

```
Route::get('mollietest', ['uses'=>'PurchaseController@index','as'=>'purchase.index']);
Route::get('paymenturl', ['uses'=>'PurchaseController@create','as'=>'purchase.create']);
Route::post('paymenturl', ['uses'=>'PurchaseController@store','as'=>'purchase.store']);
Route::get('checkout', ['uses'=>'PurchaseController@show','as'=>'purchase.show']);
```

And my PurchaseController:

```
public function index()
    {
        return View::make('mollie');
    }

public function create()
{
    // get list of issuers
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('Mollie');
    $gateway->setApiKey(mytestapi);

    $payment = $gateway->fetchPaymentMethods()->send();
    if($payment->isSuccessful()){
        $pay = $payment->getPaymentMethods();
    }


    $henk = $gateway->fetchIssuers()->send();
    if($henk->isSuccessful()){
        $issuers = $henk->getIssuers();
    }

    return View::make('gewoonbetalen')
        ->with(['issuers'=>$issuers,'pay'=>$pay]);
}

public function store()
{
    // make payment
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('Mollie');
    $gateway->setApiKey(mytestapi);

    $order_id = time();
    $params = array(
                    'amount'=>'10.00',
                    'description'=> time(),
                    'method'=>Input::get('paymentmethod'),
                    'returnUrl'=>URL::route('purchase.show'),
                    'redirectUrl'=>URL::route('purchase.show'),
                    'metadata'=> array(
                                    'order_id' => $order_id,
                                ),
                    'issuer'=>Input::get('issuer'),
                    );
    $response = $gateway->purchase($params)->send();

    Log::error('blablalllll');

    if($response->isRedirect()){
         $response->redirect(); 
    } elseif($reponse->isPending()) {
        return "Pending, Reference: ". $response->getTransactionReference();
    } else {
        return "Error " .$response->getCode() . ': ' .$response->getMessage();
    }
}

public function show($id)
{
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('Mollie');
    $gateway->setApiKey(mytestapi);
    $response = $gateway->completePurchase()->send();

    $data = $response->getData();

    print_r($data);

}
```

paymenturl view:

```
{{Form::open(array('action'=>'purchase.store','method'=>'POST'))}}

    <select name="paymentmethod">
        @foreach($pay as $payment)
            <option value="{{$payment->getId() }}">{{$payment->getName()}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <select name="issuer">
        @foreach($issuers as $issuer)
        <option value="{{ $issuer->getId() }}" name="issuer">{{$issuer->getName();}}</option>
        @endforeach
        <option value="1">of wat anders</option>
    </select>

    {{Form::submit()}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

Is there anything missing or whatever? i've been busy with this all weekend but with no success. Is there anyone who can tell me what is wrong?

**FYI: I am doing this on my localhost. Don't know if this is any problem (shouldn't be)**

Comment: So, SO ppl. What should i do if there are no comments or whatsoever?

Comment: Hi, is there anyway you can dump out your response object into a pastebin somewhere? I'd like to see it.

I believe the issue is here: 
if($response->isRedirect()){
         $response->redirect(); 
}

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. It's indeed in the redirect piece, I recommend changing the  $response->redirect(); to something like...

return Redirect::away($response->getData()['links']['paymentUrl']);

This will redirect the user away from your website to the mollie payment URL, as this will be generated when the gateway is opened and specified. Atleast, this is how I have managed to fix it.